# verify NSURL which is getting from UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, nsurl

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {    

    NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
}
```

I am getting this image url then i save this in NSUserDefaults and close my app. then i delete picture with this URL from iPhone album now when next time app runs i get imageUrl from user deafults. now i need to decide that whether this image exist or not. how i can find this.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [imageURL path];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])     //Does file exist?
{
  //Do something if the file exists or handle the case where it doesn't
}
```

Hope this helps
Tams